# sfdisk command fails in liberte setup.sh

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, mbr

I used to run Liberte Linux off a USB, but I can't seem to make the USB bootable any more.

1. Create a MBR type partition table on /dev/sdc
2. Create a FAT32 partition /dev/sdc1
3. Unzip the `/liberte` directory to /dev/sdc1
4. Copy out `/liberte/setup.sh` and unmount
5. Run `sudo sh setup.sh /dev/sdc1`

[setup.sh](http://pastebin.com/SWdrWhAt) includes the following command, quite near the end

```
sfdisk -q -A"${devpart}" "${rdev}"
```

which evaluates to

```
sfdisk -q -A1 /dev/sdc
```

which yields this error

```
sfdisk: invalid option -- '1'
```

I can't find this exact problem online, but other people are griping that sfdisk's command line arguments have changed.

**How do I tweak this to complete installation of the MBR?** (Or, how do I install Liberte to a bootable USB using modern tools?)

I've tried unetbootin, but that doesn't work either. I've dried `dd`-ing the Liberte iso as-is but that isn't bootable. Please don't reccommend an alternative OS, I want to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is true my version of *sfdisk* differs from that of [the Manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sfdisk), which carries this:

> **-A** number
>
> Make the indicated partition(s) active, and all others inactive.

while my Debian Stretch (package *util-linux version 2.29-1*) carries this:

> **-A, --activate** device [partition-number...]
>                 Switch on the bootable flag for the specified partitions.  If no partition-number  is  specified,  then  list  the partitions with an enabled flag.

According to this last instruction set, your script line should be corrected to

```
 sfdisk -q -A "${rdev}"  "${devpart}"
```

No harm in saving a copy of the original script somewhere safe, then modify the line as above, and try to run it. Let me know.